# V rip not working the same

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I'm following a Domestika tutorial and was automatically getting this rip shape when I selected  vertices and then pressed <kbd>V</kbd>, then I started getting the message rip failed, thought I did something wrong and created a new mesh still won't work. I can manually separate the rip with <kbd>G</kbd>, but it won't automatically separate. What did I do wrong?

I'm using Blender 3.0.

Also tried with a cylinder without modifiers and I can only get that shape manipulating with <kbd>G</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you can separate it, the rip worked. If you get an error "Rip Failed" but you can move the vertex with G, then it means you tried to rip a vertex that was already ripped and has only one face left it belongs to. To rip a vertex to split it, it has to be connected to at least 2 faces (or if there are no faces, only edges, it needs at least 2 edges.

Comment: The other thing is, what do you mean with "automatically separate"? When you press V to rip vertices (and it does not fail) and you directly abort the rip for example by right-clicking, the new vertex remains in its original position so the now 2 vertices are in the exact same place. If you want it to directly move somewhere you have to move your mouse before right-clicking. If you do not move your mouse and the vertex stays in the same place it can be that if you now try again to rip it with V, you get the "Rip Failed" error, because it was already ripped before but you just do not see it.

Comment: Thank you so much I truly appreciate you took the time to reply, I know it's a bit confusing, my explanation is not very good, I've taken a little video of the issue, you see, on the first video https://youtu.be/WjAVCeq1eGc I'm literally not moving the mouse and the rip automatically separates, but on the second clip https://youtu.be/Jna6rwbLJ7M you can see it separates automatically the first time but not the second or the third time, but it's clear there's a rip, I really don't understand :(.

Comment: First of all: nothing is really separating there. The vertices stay in place, it's just the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier rounding the edges because after the rip they are no longer connected and treated as a continuous piece. In the second video you can clearly see that when you first rip it on the side, there appears a little split in the mesh, but different than before. So I guess there are some flaws in your geometry like duplicate vertices etc. which are not visible just looking at it in a video. Have you tried to select all with A and then M > _Merge_ > _By Distance_?